# Not allowing an app to open before a certain date

Tags: android

I started writing an app for a good friend of mine for her birthday and I want to give it to her on time. But we're both on holiday when it's her birthday, so my question is, if you can stop an app from opening before a certain date. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest two options:

1. Easy to make but not so elegant: Put a password at the first activity and give to her at her birthday
2. Put a countdown into the app, which will create a Button, when the countdown is finished. This could be "hacked" easily by her for example through changing the date on her phone but would be more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the date and close the app if it is before your desired date.

This doesn't really work if she changes the date on her phone though.

A more usable solution would be to have a screen that checks the date against an online service, and show a message telling her to wait if it is before the desired date. Keep timezones in mind if you go down this path.

If it's past the desired date, you can have this screen start the rest of your Activities.